# Can not render component correctly in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which renders post on page.
On this component I have comments section.
In addition I have 2 components one for if user is not comment author and another one if the user is comment author.
Difference is that if user is author of the comment,comments will render with delete/edit buttons.

Now about the problem.

```
const checkCommentAuthor = (): boolean => {
  return comments.map((item: any): boolean => {
      if (item.username === localStorage.getItem("username")) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  };

  return (
  checkCommentAuthor ?  (
    < IsCommentAuthor />
  ) : ( <IsNotCommentAuthor/> )
  );
};
```

If I have 2 comments on the post and let's say only one comment belongs to me(I mean I'm the author) the function will return `<IsCommentAuthor/>` for both of them.
Is there any possible way to return  `<IsNotCommentAuthor/>` for some comments and `< IsCommentAuthor />` for some?

Comment: Yes this is possible you just need to check conditional rendering part https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html. Also seems like there is syntax error with < IsCommentAuthor /> extra space at the beginning

Comment: Post the content of item array also

Comment: @cauchy as I understood.I can pass function to the return() right?

Comment: What is the second return for? This isn't correct code, it isn't reachable.

Comment: I thought that way i could return the function result

Comment: Unless it's just poor formatting or I'm misunderstanding your snippet it appears you just return an array of booleans from `checkCommentAuthor`. Even if you hit the second return, even an empty array (`[]`) is a truthy value and only the happy path `IsCommentAuthor` would be returned.

Comment: Yes I check on which comment it returns true and on which false and depending on that I'm returning <IsCommentAuthor/> and <IsNotCommentAuthor/>

Comment: Can you help me to fix it please ?

Comment: If all you are trying to do is to map `comments` to `IsCommentAuthor` or `IsNotCommentAuthor` components then @MeetZaveri's answer looks like it does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return components in functions also.

Like

```
const checkCommentAuthor = () => {
  return comments.map((item) =>
    item.username === localStorage.getItem('username') ? (
      <IsCommentAuthor />
    ) : (
      <IsNotCommentAuthor />
    )
  )
}
```

Also in your code, there are two `return()` defined so only first one will return the function and code will never reach to next `return()`

Comment: Sorry, totally tangential, but why not `const username = localStorage.getItem('username')` once and just `if (item.username === username) ...` each iteration?

Comment: I still get the same result tho :/ I'm passing it like this  ` const checkCommentAuthor = () => {
    return comments.map((item : any) =>
      item.username === localStorage.getItem('username') ? (
        <IsCommentAuthor />
      ) : (
        <IsNotCommentAuthor />
      )
    )
  }

  return checkCommentAuthor();
};
`

Comment: Yes but your code has extra `return()` defined which kinda makes no sense. Because the first `return()` will exit from function by return value thus leaving unused code below it.